# How to start Bottle as a daemon from another script?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, daemon, bottle

I would like to use [BottlePy](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/) as a daemon started from another script and I have issues turning a standalone script (`webserver.py`) into a class. The standalone version of my webserver below works fine:

```
import bottle

@bottle.get('/hello')
def hello():
    return 'Hello World'

@bottle.error(404)
def error404(error):
    return 'error 404'

bottle.run(host='localhost', port=8080)
```

My intent is now to start it from the main script below as

```
from webserver import WebServer
from multiprocessing import Process

def start_web_server():
    # initialize the webserver class
    WebServer()

# mainscript.py operations
p = Process(target=start_web_server)
p.daemon = True
p.start()
# more operations
```

where `WebServer()` would be in the naively now-modified `webserver.py`:

```
import bottle

class WebServer():
    def __init__(self):
        bottle.run(host='localhost', port=8080)

    @bottle.get('/hello')
    def hello(self):
        return 'Hello World'

    @bottle.error(404)
    def error404(self, error):
        return 'error 404'
```

**What works**: the whole thing starts and the webserver is listening

**What does not work**: upon calling `http://localhost:8080/hello`

```
127.0.0.1 - - [11/Dec/2013 10:16:23] "GET /hello HTTP/1.1" 500 746
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\bottle.py", line 764, in _handle
    return route.call(**args)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\bottle.py", line 1575, in wrapper
    rv = callback(*a, **ka)
TypeError: hello() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)
```

My questions are:

- what kind of parameters am I expected to pass to `hello()` and `error404()`?
- what should I do in order to parametrize `@bottle.get('/hello')`? I would like to have something like `@bottle.get(hello_url)` but where should `hello_url = '/hello'` be initialized? (`self.hello_url` is unknown to `@bottle.get`)

---

**EDIT**: while preparing a fork of this question to handle question 2 (about the parametrization) I had an epiphany and tried the obvious solution which works (code below). I am not that used to classes yet so I did not have the reflex to add the variable in the scope of the class.

```
# new code with the path as a parameter
class WebServer():

    myurl = '/hello'

    def __init__(self):
        bottle.run(host='localhost', port=8080, debug=True)

    @bottle.get(myurl)
    def hello():
        return 'Hello World'

    @bottle.error(404)
    def error404(error):
        return 'error 404'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> what kind of parameters am I expected to pass to hello() and error404()?

The short answer: none.  Just remove `self` and they should start to work.

```
@bottle.get('/hello')
def hello():
    return 'Hello World'

@bottle.error(404)
def error404(error):
    return 'error 404'
```

---

> what should I do in order to parametrize @bottle.get('/hello')? I
>   would like to have something like @bottle.get(hello_url) but where
>   should hello_url = '/hello' be initialized? (self.hello_url is unknown
>   to @bottle.get)

I can interpret this a couple of different ways, so I'm not sure how to help you.  But since this is a completely separate question (with potentially a much larger scope), please consider asking it in a new, separate SO question.

Comment: Ha. I thought that one always has to pass `self` to a method. Thank you - it works!

Comment: I will follow your suggestion and ask a separate question for the second part