# how to integrate Bottle into a script?

Tags: python, tkinter, bottle

I have a `Tkinter` application which makes use of a webserver (`Bottle`) to get some data to display. The current setup is to start a `Process` with the webserver in the application. This is unfortunately the only way I found to allow for both the windows application and `Bottle` to run their `.mainloop()` and `.run()`, respectively. A skeleton of the app is below

```
# main application file
import Tkinter as tk
from multiprocessing import Process
import testb

class App():
    def __init__(self):
        self.msg = "hello"
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.callback()

    def callback(self):
        # things happen here
        self.root.after(10000, self.callback)  

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = App()
    proc = Process(target=testb.WebServer, args=(app.msg,))
    proc.start()
    app.root.mainloop()
```

and

```
# this is the testb.py imported above
import bottle

class WebServer():
    def __init__(self, msg):
        self.msg = msg
        bottle.route('/', 'GET', self.main)
        bottle.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8080, debug=False, quiet=True)

    def main(self):
        return self.msg
```

What I would like to do is to get rid of the `Process` (mostly to simplify the code and the logic in the actual application) and make it so that the webserver is run as part of the main application. I realize that I have two "hanging entities" (both the UI and the webserver are constantly waiting for events) but maybe there is a way to concurrently run such activities?

Note: I am actually trying to get away from [a previous solution discussed some months ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20515534/how-to-start-bottle-as-a-daemon-from-another-script).

Comment: Not sure if this question is valid, but why do you need a web server to display data in your GUI?